# How can I link lists?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

Do you know a way to insert objects from another list into a list?  Like so:

```
List<FoodItem> top10 = [
    pizza[1],
    burger[0],
    snacks[3],
  ];
```

That probably sounds confusing now, but I would like to briefly explain to you why I need it.
As you can see I have different lists of food. I would now like to create a Top10 list that shows the 10 best dishes of all dishes.
So every FoodItem from top10 is also a member of other lists.
For example, if the best dish is a Prosciutto Pizza, then the dish is at number 1 on the Top10 list, but also on the pizza list.

Now a variable of the FoodItem is changed from time to time while using the app.
I want the changes to the variable to be visible in the other lists.

Do you understand?

Comment: You list are already defined to contain references to `FoodItem` objects (so the list does not actually contain the objects itself). So if the same object are referred to in two lists, then updates from one list will automatically also be seen in the other list.

Comment: Yep that's the case because these FoodItem objects are getting assigned by reference. Do you understand assigning by reference and assigning by value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a score field in FoodItem to judge whether it is better than another. If so, you can add a compare function:

```
int compareFood(FoodItem food1, FoodItem food2) => food1.score > food2.score ? -1 : 1;
```

Then, you can get a sorted food list:

```
List<FoodItem> get sortedSnacks {
  var list = snacks.toList();
  list.sort(compareFood);
  return list;
}
```

For top10:

```
List<FoodItem> get allFoods => [
      ...pizaa,
      ...burger,
      ...snacks,
    ];

List<FoodItem> get top10 {
  var list = allFoods.toList();
  list.sort(compareFood);
  return list.sublist(0, list.length >= 10 ? 10 : list.length);
}
```

Comment: This is really smart! Thank you for your quick and detailed answer!
So I can only filter out the dishes that I want to transfer to the database! Thank you my friend :D

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there.

You can define top10 as 'FoodItems' provided Pizza, Burger and Snack classes inherirts from there. In case it is not possible for any reason then you can define top10 as List. The debug window at the left in the screenshot below shows that 'universalList' contains two lists - pizzas and pastas.

[image]

Comment: So I can only integrate complete lists in top10, right?

Comment: Either a complete list of a filtered one, as you need. For example, `universalList.add(pastas.where((pasta) => pasta.price <= 10);`   I just gave you a sample code to demonstrate how it works. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can insert an object from a list into another with:

```
top10.add(2, pizzas.get(0));
```

In this sample code you are inserting the first element from the pizzas's list into the position 2 of the top10 list. It's important to know that when you insert a object from a list you're inserting the reference to the object, not doing a copy of that object, so the object is the same. If you edit a property in the pizza's object, you will see the changes also in the top10's object (these are both the same object).

Comment: Oh, that's really great! I was looking for such a simple solution! Does that go the other way too? So if I change something in top10. Will the change also be shown in pizza?

Comment: Yes, if you edit an object from top10 you will see the change in pizza, because it is the same object.